# Avoid: multicol Error: Error saving partial page

Tags: errors, multicol, dtx

In my package I am using in the dtx file the ltxdoc class which uses multicol for the index.

Currently I get this error:

> ! Package multicol Error: Error saving partial page.
>
> See the multicol package documentation for explanation.
>
> l.1 \begin{theindex}
>
> The part of the page before the multicols environment was nearly full with
>   the result that starting the environment will produce an overfull page. Some
>   text may be lost! Please increase \premulticols either generally or for this
>    environment by specifying a suitable value in the second optional argument to
>   the multicols environment.

However even if I include something like

```
\setlength\premulticols{10\baselineskip}
```

this does not change anything.

In the document pdf the error is that the index runs into the bottom of the page instead of starting at a new page.

An obvious solution would be to add an `\clearpage` at the end of the dtx file

```
% \clearpage
% \Finale
\endinput
```

but if this can be solved otherwise I would like to know it.

Comment: are you using the second optional argument already (if so, `\premulticols` is not used)

Comment: second optional argument of which command? I did not find any argument defintion of `\premulticols`.

Comment: the multicols environment: `\premulticols` is the default value of that argument but is not used if the argument is used.

Comment: This is code inside of ltxdoc.cls or doc.sty . I can not fix it in my code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`doc` package uses

```
    {\begin{multicols}\c@IndexColumns[\index@prologue][\IndexMin]%
```

So the second optional argument of `multicols` is used, so the default value of that argument `\premulticols` is never referenced. Instead you need to set the length `\IndexMin` (which defaults to 80pt)

Comment: I have the same problem, but this answer is too elliptic for me to fully understand and implement. Could you please explain step by step? Thanks!

Comment: @Mårten use `\setlength\IndexMin{...}` for some length ... that works for you, the initial value being 80pt

Comment: Thanks! Could you just please tell me whether I should put it in the preamble, at the beginning of the document, or before every {multicols}?

Comment: @Mårten preamble probably

Comment: It tells me that \setlength\IndexMin{100pt} is an "Undefined Control Sequence"...

Comment: @Mårten IndexMin is defined by doc.sty which is included by the ltxdoc class so will be defined in the preamble. If you have problems it is best to ask a new question with a _complete_ small document that shows the problem